# sum inside if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

somebody can explain me why this code:

```
$a = 0.1;
$b = 0.2;

if ($a + $b == 0.3) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "KO";
}
```

returns *KO*?

I don't understand why the sum result is different the float 0.3, considering that:

```
var_dump($a + $b);
```

returns: *float(0.3)*

The only hypothesis I have is that the comparison is made between only $b and 0.3 but the doubt remains because also in this case:

```
if ( ($a + $b) == 0.3) {
```

I get *KO*..

Comment: If you set the precision than the comparison will be done, otherwise not.

Comment: $a + $b  -.3 = 5.5511151231258E-17

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#113703

Comment: See this example: [https://3v4l.org/0Ad6A](https://3v4l.org/0Ad6A)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Offtopic: how do you not get confused when using `OK` and `KO`. I mean, I would often overlook the difference.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#113703](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#113703) answers perfectly to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a floating point number and the precision of this number is not fixed, if you fixed the precision than it will be okey.

[Check Online](https://3v4l.org/0Ad6A)

```
$a = 0.1;
$b = 0.2;
$c = sprintf('%.1f', ($a + $b));
if ($c  == 0.3) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "KO";
}
```

the result is `OK` now.

Answer (score 0):

Use function round($a+b, 1); I have this problem in my code